# Second WPF window is blank

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The second window in my WPF window is blank.

I've tried declaring the variable in multiple places, and assigning the value of `new Send()` separately from the declaration.

I've also made sure it isn't just *my computer*. I sent the compiled program to someone else and it did the same thing.

```cs
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Send send = new Send();
            send.Show();
        }
```

The Send class:

```cs
    public partial class Send : Window
    {
        public Send()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ipIdBox.Text = GenerateIPID(GetIPAddress(), 8000);
        }

        private string GetIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
        }

        private string GenerateIPID(string ip, int port)
        {
            string[] ipseps = ip.Split('.'); // Split IP into parts
            string code = ""; // Initialize the code
            int counter = 0; // A counter (because every 4 digits are seperated)
            foreach (string ippart in ipseps)
            {
                int ipparti = Convert.ToInt32(ippart);
                string hippart = ipparti.ToString("X2");
                code += hippart;
                counter++;
                if (counter == 1) {
                    counter = 0;
                    code += "-";
                }
            }
            code += $"-{port.ToString("X4")}";
            return code;
        }

    }
```

... and it's XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="ScistMain.Send"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScistMain"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Send" Height="264.95" Width="451.774" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Topmost="True">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ipIdBox" Margin="0,124,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="34" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Text="7F00-0001-8000"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,108,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tell the person recieving to type this code:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="You are sending:" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Image x:Name="iconImg" Height="32" Margin="206,39,206,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Source="Resources/scist.ico"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Placeholder Program" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="pBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="10,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="359,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I expect it to show the window I created in the designer:

[image]

but instead it shows a black window.

[image]

Comment: Something is up with your `Send` class. We don't know nothing about your `Send` class, so we can't really say anything more...

Comment: @elgonzo I just added it

Comment: There is really nothing there in the code-behind that seems to be related to the issue. What does the XAML of the `Send` class look like?

Comment: @elgonzo Added that too

Comment: Hmm, the XAML does not contain anything suspicious either (it's rather simple and straighforward). Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. If that does not help, create another new WPF application solution/project for test purposes. As first step, just add the Send class and its XAML to this new project. Let it assign just a dummy value to `ipIdBox.Text` (don't call `GenerateIPID(...)`, yet). Run it and see whether Send works properly. If it does, add step-by-step more pieces of the code from your original project to it, and run it again after each step until the problem reoccurs. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) When the problem occurs, you know that the last piece of code is either the cause of the problem, or it is at least a necessary contribution for the problem to occur. From there, you can then start a more thourough diagnosis/code analysis/troubleshooting...

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding did nothing to help me. I'm creating a new project right now...

Comment: It seems to be the XAML itself. Copying and pasting the Send XAML to the new project, and changing the namespace values, etc. shows a blank screen also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194343/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-scottbeebiwan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OverridesDefaultStyle="True"` on the `Window` tag was the issue.